# List does not display

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

My list does not display anymore.

List URL like:

```
https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/patrick_fiset_uqtr_ca/Lists/listtest?env=WebViewList
```

[image: empty list]

Where is my list data?

By the way, I was first trying to post at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint
But I always get "Correct the highlighted errors and try again.", and nothing is highlighted. So it's impossible for me to post there.

Comment: Same for me. However the lists display well in a SharePoint page list webpart on SharePoint online

Comment: I have not encountered a problem with my testing here, please try using another browser or have one of your other colleagues see if the problem persists.

Comment: It display correctly since yesterday.